# How to replace words in proposal using regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I have following task: to replace word for word ***word*** in proposal using regular expressions. I have made following code:

```
p=Pattern.compile(word);
m=p.matcher(source);    
source=m.replaceAll("<b><i>"+word+"</i></b>");
```

"source"-source string, "word" - finding word. But it doesn't work. For example, there is string "1234 123.". I need to replace "123" word (word can be framed with "." or " " (space)) in this string, but i have made `"<b><i>123</i></b>4 <b><i>123</i></b>"`, that is incorrect. How should I change my code? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly. But you probably want to add word boundaries to your regex:

```
p = Pattern.compile("\b" + word + "\b");
```

Comment: Result text doesn't contain any framed words.

Answer (score 1):

This should help. Note that `\\` is used to escape `\` . [Below code allows multiple words to be highlighted].

`\b` matches word boundaries so if you wrap a word with `\b` regex will match whole word.

```
    String source="1234 123 345 123456";
    String words="123|345";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(" + words + ")\\b");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(source);    
    source=m.replaceAll("<b><i>$1</i></b>"); 
    System.out.println(source);
```

**Output**

```
1234 <b><i>123</i></b> <b><i>345</i></b> 123456
```

1234 ***123*** ***345*** 123456

But note the *caveat* that if your input text is already marked up, your words might not be matched
Ex

```
String source="1<b><i>23</i></b>";//This does not match 123 !
```

---

**Edit**

Use this pattern if you are expecting your words end with optional `.`

```
Pattern.compile("\\b(" + words + ")[.]?\\b");
```

Comment: Thank you. I have 1 question - it will work correctly, if i have source "1234 123." and word is "123 (the result should be "1234 <b><i>123</i></b>."). Right?

Comment: No `123.` is treated as single word

Comment: Updated with expected regex however If you update Question with all possible scenarios we would be able to help further

Comment: Also Please consider accepting the answer that you think is the best :)

Comment: Sorry, I was away. Please, edit your answer, that your regular expression know all main punctuation marks (,.?!;:). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep things simple:

```
source.replaceAll("\\b" + word + "\\b", "$0 <b><i>$0</i></b>");
```

Here's a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "1234 123.";
    String word = "123";
    String newSource = source.replaceAll("\\b" + word + "\\b", "$0 <b><i>$0</i></b>");
    System.out.println(newSource);
}
```

Output:

```
1234 123 <b><i>123</i></b>.
```

So, how does this work?

- Regex `\b` means "word boundary", so `"\\bword\\b"` will match your word (double backslashes because java swallows one of them in the escape for backslash)
- `$0` in the replace String means the entire match

I kept things simple too my *not* using a Pattern - just use the String API